# Gutenberg get index of gutenberg innerblock

Tags: block-editor

I have a `Quiz` block that contains `Question`s blocks that have `Answer` blocks. Both `Quiz` and `Question` use `InnerBlocks` to allow questions or answers to be dragged around, edited and saved.

When I save the Quiz, how can I get the index of each question in `question/save.js` and the index of each question and answer in each `answer/save.js`.

I would like this so I can give all checkbox unique ids, like

```
<input id="q1-a3" />
```

And label the questions things like "Question 1."

Quiz/save.js

```
return (
  <div {...blockProps}>
    <InnerBlocks.Content />
  </div>
);
```

Question/save.js

```
return (
  <div {...blockProps}>
    <h3>Question {numToWords(1)}</h3>
    <ul class="quiz--answers">
      <InnerBlocks.Content />
    </ul>
  </div>
);
```

Answer/save.js

```
return (
  <li {...blockProps}>
    <input id="checkbox-2" type="checkbox" value="checkbox-2" />
    <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox-2">
      {JSON.stringify(attributes)}
      {attributes.text}
      <span class="quiz--answer-content">{attributes.explanation}</span>
    </label>
  </li>
);
```

I have tried using `getBlockIndex( clientId )` to try to get the index of each block, however I'm not sure where to use this as it always returns -1. It also only seems that `clientId` is available in the edit function, and I think I want it in the save function unless I go about adding it to the block attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may now retrieve the index of a inner block via the `core/block-editor` data module. You may pair it with the `useSelect` hook to keep the indexes up to date on changes.

Something like this. *Intentionally verbose for clarity.*

```
import {useSelect} from '@wordpress/data';

const Answer = ( blockProps ) => {
    const {index} = useSelect( select => {
        const {getBlockIndex} = select( 'core/block-editor' );
        return {
            index: getBlockIndex( blockProps.clientId );
        }
    } );

    return ( <li {...blockProps}>
        <input id="checkbox-2" type="checkbox" value="checkbox-2" />
        <label className="checkbox" htmlFor="checkbox-2">
            {JSON.stringify( blockProps.attributes )}
            {index}
            <span className="quiz--answer-content">{blockProps.attributes.explanation}</span>
        </label>
    </li> );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try saving the values in html data attributes. then get them using `getAttribute("data-index")`

```
data-index="number"
```

usually in save.js you can't use useStates and useEffects. you have to make another file that uses vanilla js to do the logic. save.js is saved as a pure html elements.

Comment: How would I get those values?

Comment: save.js most not contain any logic. As I told, you use vanllia js in another file. And use document.querySelector to grap the element, then get its data attribute using element.getAttribute("data-index").

Comment: If you want more help, and exactly how to do it. i need to see all your code. edit.js and save.js....

Comment: But usually when you want to add some functionality to your save.js, you use vanilla js in the traditional way. Not through react. Though, it is possible to use React in the frontend. But that is a different topic.

Comment: Let me know if that worked for you.

Comment: Maybe I did not understand your question right. Why do want to get the index of innerblocks in save.js, what would you do with these indexes?

Comment: I would like to save a question name like "Question 1." "Question 2." "Question 3." using the questions' index. And I would like to use the question index and the answer index to give some checkboxes unique ids, so question 1 answer 1 would be `<input type="checkbox" id="q1-a1"/>` and answer 2 would be `<input type="checkbox" id="q1-a2"/>` etc. Thanks for trying to help

Comment: These questions are created in edit.js, right? I mean, these questions and answers are created in editor. If that is so. In the process of creating these blocks, why don't u save the indexes in the attributes of the quiz block and then pass them to  save.js.

Comment: Hey @shadi, thanks for the advice on the Edit function. I think we were talking about two different things, but your tip on setting everything in there (no logic in save) was able to help me do what I needed to and I have answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

The `Quiz` block was the top level block. So in its Edit function, I created a subscribe method. I was able to [select](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-data/#select) the editor and get the current block:

```
// Subscribe to all changes of the Gutenberg blocks
wp.data.subscribe(() => {
  const quiz = wp.data.select("core/editor").getBlock(clientId);
  triggerUpdate(quiz);
});
```

The subscribe method is covered briefly here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQczO6VOMkY

This `subscribe()` happened to be called thousands of times as the page was edited, so I was unable to work out a better way of working with it than to manually "debounce" it:

```
// Debounce that change, so it wouldn't trigger thousands of times
let timeouts = [];

const triggerUpdate = (quiz) => {
  while (timeouts.length) {
    clearTimeout(timeouts.shift());
  }

  const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    // ... the code to get the index of each block
  }, 1000);
  timeouts.push(timeout);
};
```

Now I had a function triggering every time I updated the post, I just needed to actually get the indexes. This was easily done by using `.innerBlocks`, once on the `quiz` (which I'd already got by using `wp.data.select("core/editor").getBlock(clientId)`) and then once on each `question`.

With that, I could loop through each block and update its attributes using [updateBlockAttributes](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core-block-editor/#updateblockattributes)

```
// Loop through all nested blocks and update relevant attributes
quiz.innerBlocks.forEach((question, q) => {
  let qid = "q" + (q + 1); // qid = "q1", "q2" etc
  if (question.attributes.qid != qid) {
    const update = {
      qid,
      questionTitle: "Question " + numToWords(parseInt(q + 1)),
    };
    console.log(update);
    dispatch("core/editor").updateBlockAttributes(
      question.clientId,
      update
    );
  }
  question.innerBlocks.forEach((answer, a) => {
    let aid = qid + "a" + (a + 1); // aid = "q1a2" etc
    if (answer.attributes.qid != qid) {
      dispatch("core/editor").updateBlockAttributes(answer.clientId, {
        aid,
      });
    }
  });
});
```